# Merge cells horizontally in Visual Studio 2008 SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

In my SSRS rdl report, I have 3 cells that I want to merge. According to [this instruction on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207131(v=sql.105).aspx), I am supposed to select the cell, right click and click **Merge Cells**. However I do not see such option.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what to do please?

Comment: You can't merge those cells because the left cell is in another Group (hence the dashed lines between the left and middle cell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge cell option only work when all the cells are in the same group, however in your case it appears like the left most cell belong to different group. Try applying merge cell functionality on the right two cell, merge cell option will appear.